# Console command test never completes when response hidden

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

In Symfony 2.6 a test of a console command that requests a password, the test never completes (and never times out) if the response is set to hidden with `$question->setHidden(true);`  Commenting out the line allows the test to complete with success.  [The same was true with DialogHelper and its equivalent method of hiding the response rather than as shown here with QuestionHelper.]

#### Edit:

The above description relates to a test of the interactive console command.  Testing the command itself with the test below results in `RuntimeException: Aborted` at `$input->setArgument('username', $helper->ask($input, $output, $question));`

#### The command

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question;

class CreateUserCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
...
    protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $helper = $this->getHelper('question');

        $question = new Question('Please enter a password: ');
        $question->setValidator(function ($answer) {
            if (empty($answer)) {
                throw new \RuntimeException(
                'A password is required'
                );
            }
            return $answer;
        });
        $question->setHidden(true);
        $question->setMaxAttempts(5);

        $input->setArgument('password', $helper->ask($input, $output, $question));
    ...
    }
...
}
```

#### Interactive test

```
public function testExecute()
{
    $kernel = $this->createKernel();
    $kernel->boot();

    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->add(new CreateUserCommand());

    $command = $application->find('truckee:user:create');
    $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);

    $dialog = $command->getHelper('question');
    $dialog->setInputStream($this->getInputStream("bborko\n"
                    . "Benny\n "
                    . "Borko\n "
                    . "bborko@bogus.info\n "
                    . "123Abcd\n "
                    . "sandbox\n"
    ));
    $commandTester->execute(array('command' => $command->getName()));

    $this->assertRegExp('/.../', $commandTester->getDisplay());
}
```

#### Console test

```
    public function testCreateAdmin()
    {
        $kernel = $this->createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();

        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->add(new CreateUserCommand());

        $command = $application->find('truckee:user:create');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute(
                array(
                    'username' => 'bborko',
                    'firstname' => 'Benny',
                    'lastname' => 'Borko',
                    'email' => 'bborko@bogus.info',
                    'password' => '123Abcd',
                    'type' => 'admin',
                )
        );
        $this->assertRegExp('/.../', $commandTester->getDisplay());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again I learn that Windows is not the best of places to develop in Symfony.  Today I found

> $this->markTestSkipped('This test is not supported on Windows');

in Symfony\Component\Console\Tests\Helper\QuestionHelperTest `public function testAskHiddenResponse()`.

If you want to learn what tests are not supported, search on the text 'Windows' in the `vendor\symfony` directory (e.g., with an IDE like Netbeans).